# How to adopt MVC in a web application?

Tags: javascript, html, css, model-view-controller, web-applications

I'm currently working on a web application which uses HTML, CSS, Javascript, Bootstrap and JQuery. I will like to use Model–view–controller (MVC) as my software design pattern. So far I have 7 HTML pages and each page has a corresponding controller in Javascript. And these HTML pages shared some "global" CSS & Javascript (Bootstrap & JQuery). I'm unsure how to organise my files to demonstrate MVC clearly. Am I right to say:

- MODEL (some files which manippulate data?)
- VIEW (all my HTML & CSS files)
- CONTROLLER (all my Javascript files)

Does this means I have 3 folders (MODEL, VIEW, CONTROLLER) and I simply place all my files accordingly?

Sorry is my 1st time adopting software design pattern, sorry for any confusion caused. I will like to know more about how to implement MVC effectively as I feel is important.

Answer (score 1):

Well it depends on the approach. But to give you a clue of best practice you don't necessarily need to have a controller for each page, in fact it will be more like a view for each page, a model for each data entity and a controller for performing the actions of data binding, in most of the cases you will be having a similar number of controllers and models. The controller usually will be the one choosing which view to show, parsing the data for such a purpose, and invoking data synchronization actions. Keep in mind : "controllers does stuff".

Comment: Thank you so much for the clear explanation. I always have this mindset where controller is all the methods/functions for a webpage. So it seems like controller is tightly linked with model.

Answer (score 1):

You can read about **MVP pattern** (Model-View-Presenter) which similar with MVC and used in frontend.

Also you can see examples of todolist mvc ([vanilla javascript](https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/tree/master/examples/vanillajs), [jquery](https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/tree/master/examples/jquery)). Here is cool code organization.

What about folder structure, You can apply different approaches, but for several pages it's good idea to create folders like `models`, `views`, `controllers`, `helpers` and so on.

p.s. Together with the `models` usually used `collections` (list of models). You can see how organized [Backbone](http://backbonejs.org/) (library) structure.

Comment: Thank you so much. That's a lot of new information. Am I right to say todolist mvc, folder structure and backbone can be implemented concurrently in a web application? For my case, if I wish to start off with folder structure, how should I organise my files? Thank you once again.

Comment: Yes, you are right and it's about JS code.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/24199418/6554441 - here about folder structure for simple frontend project in generally. And I like this approach: _CSS_, _JS_, _IMAGE_ forder is placed to `assets` or `resource` folder. If `data` files (you call it "model") are used in _JS_, I would put it in _JS/data_. If you have a lot of HTML, I would put it in _templates_ folder.